# Не работает вход через laravel и не могу найти в чём причина)

Tags: laravel

Код контроллера

```
public function login(Request $request){
        if (Auth::check()){
            return redirect(route('Account'));
        }

        $formFields = $request->only(['Login', 'Password']);

//        dd($formFields);

        if(Auth::attempt($formFields)){
            return redirect()->intended(route('Account'));
        }

        return redirect(route('LoginPage'))->withErrors([
            'Login' => 'Произошла ошибка при входе!',
        ]);
    }
```

Ошибок не выдаёт просто пропускает условие как будто пустое значение в массиве и исполняет следующий код

```
return redirect(route('LoginPage'))->withErrors([
            'Login' => 'Произошла ошибка при входе!',
        ]);
```

Код модели User

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password){
        $this->attributes['Password'] = Hash::make($password);
    }
```

Код страницы

```
<div class="FormAuth">
            <p class="p7">Вход</p>
            <form class="formReg" action="{{route('login')}}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <input type="text" name="Login" value="" placeholder="Введите логин" class="input">
                @error('Login')
                <div><p class="p6">{{$message}}</p></div>
                @enderror
                <input type="password" name="Password" value="" placeholder="Введите пароль" class="input">
                @error('Password')
                <div><p>{{$message}}</p></div>
                @enderror
                <button type="submit" class="btn-reg log-btn" value="#"><p class="p9">Войти</p></button>
            </form>
            <a href="{{route('Authentication')}}" class="cnp-auth"><p class="p9 pCorrected">Нажмите сюда если хотите зарегистрироваться!</p></a>
        </div>
```

Через dd данные норм с формы отправляются а дальше хз что не работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот проектик:

[[тута =)]](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/w8Sq/7ZfT5SMgU)

Answer (score 0):

Крч проблема с названиями в бд нельзя писать Password вместо password я находил что якобы эта функция заменяет стандартное название

```
public function  getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->attributes['Название твоего столбца в бд'];
        
        // или

        return $this->Название твоего столбца в бд;
    }
```

Но у меня это не возымело эффекта

Ещё я пробовал поковыряться в файлике по пути vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подставив за место password своё название и это тоже не заробило скорее всего у меня руки из ж и я просто смирился и поменял название столбца на password в бд